# Getting an error making post request to openAi whisper model

Tags: fetch, blob, form-data, openai-api, openai-whisper

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GbD6.jpg)

```js
const handleUpload = async () => {
    const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: "audio/webm" });


    const formData = {
      file:audioBlob,
      model:"whisper-1"
    }


    fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "audio/webm",
        Authorization: `Bearer REDACTED_OPENAIKEY`,
        
      },
      body:formData,
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));

  };
```

I have provided the model name it is returning an error
with message

```
error:{message:"you must provide a model parameter"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Content-Type` header for this request is not correct.

According to [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/audio/create?lang=curl) it should `multipart/form-data`

if you are using Javascript you can use the [Official JS library](https://github.com/openai/openai-node).

```js
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
const resp = await openai.createTranscription(
  fs.createReadStream("audio.mp3"),
  "whisper-1"
);
```